# symmetric-appearing redirection doesn't produce the same results

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm trying to understand bash redirection, but I stumbled upon a strange example. Consider the following interaction.

```
1: $ echo "Hello" 11>txt 11<&1
2: Hello
3: $ cat txt
4: $ echo "Hello" 11>txt 1>&11
5: $ cat txt
6: Hello
```

Line 1 and 4 seems to me perfectly symmetric, why don't they produce the same result?

Comment: Why should symmetric operations produce the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you point fd11 to txt, but then you change fd11 to point to fd1, so the output goes to the terminal.

In the second case, you point fd11 to txt and then change stdout to point to it, so the output goes to the file.

You can achieve the same behaviour using the `<&` operator if you swap the descriptors:

```
echo Hello 11>txt 1<&11
```

Comment: In fact, there's no absolutely no difference between `<&` and `>&`: `echo hello 11>txt 1<&11` will write hello to txt. Both will `dup2(11, 1)` (possibly in a more round-about way). This is not a great answer.

Comment: @pizdelect: True, thanks. I updated the answer. `man bash` talks about input/output descriptors, which confused me.

Answer (score 4):

@choroba gave a good answer, but no explanation. Here is why.

`echo "Hello" 11>txt 11<&1`

- stdout -> terminal
- `11>txt` open file txt as fd/x redirect fd/11 to fd/x (copy number in fd/x into fd/11)
- `11<&1` redirect fd/11 to fd/1 (copy number in fd/1 into fd/11).

now fd/11 is equivalent to fd/1 (terminal). fd/x points to file (but we don't know x).

- `echo "Hello" 11>txt 1>&11`
- stdout -> terminal
- `11>txt` open file txt as fd/x redirect fd/11 to fd/x (copy number in fd/x into fd/11)
- `1>&11` redirect 1 to 11 (copy number in fd/11 into fd/1).

now fd/1, fd/11, and fd/x point to file.